# Substitution not clear

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, algebraic-number-theory

Let $M$ be a finite free module over a PRINCIPAL ideal domain $A$. Furthermore, let $\psi \in M^*$ be any functional into $A$ and $\varphi \in M^*$ a fixed functional into $A$. Suppose, we have that

$\varphi(x)\mid \psi(x)$ for a fixed $x\in M$ and $\varphi(x)\mid \varphi(y)$ for all $y\in M$.

It then follows (apparently from just these two divisibility relations) that we may substitute $y$ by $y-\frac{\varphi(y)}{\varphi(x)}x$ and therefore $\varphi(y)=0$. The same goes for $\psi$ which we may replace by $\psi -\frac{\psi(x)}{\varphi(x)}\varphi$ and therefore $\psi(x)=0$.

This was an excerpt of Siegfried Bosch - Algebra, 8.ed., p.75, german edition.

I have absolutely no idea how this substitution was obtained and no idea why I am allowed to do so.

Comment: Wait, by 'may' you mean that $\phi(y) = \phi(y - \frac{\phi(y)}{\phi(x)}x)$ for all $y$?

Comment: @Vincent Yes, which in turn implies that $\phi(y)=0$ for all $y\in M$.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be right. Let $\phi$ and $\psi$ be any linear functionals and just pick your fixed $x$ such that $\phi(x) = 1$. Then the divisibility conditions are satisfied, but this does not mean anything should be 0.

Also, looking at it from the other side: if $\phi$ is indeed identically zero as your source claims, then so is $\phi(x)$ for your specific $x$ and the divisibility conditions stop to make sense.

Are you sure you are quoting the book correctly?

Comment: In the book the author wants to show, that there is a $x\in M$ with $\text{cont}(x)\mid \text{cont}(y)$ for all $y\in M$. x has the property of being the maximal element with $cont(y_1)\cdot A\subset cont(y_2)\cdot A\subset ... \subset cont(x)\cdot A$. I probably skip too much of the proof, but the proof is a whole page.

Comment: What is cont? How does it relate to what you wrote in the question?

Comment: cont is the content of an element of $A$. For every $x\in M$ there is a $\varphi\in M^*$ with $\varphi(x)=cont(x)$. Nevertheless, this stage in the proof seems highly suspicious to me.

Comment: It is certainly suspicious. Given that I wrote a counterexample for the case that $\varphi$ is generic, we know that we need to use some very particular properties of the content-function to make it work - not just any functional $\varphi$ will do. In particular it seems crucial that the content function cannot take on the value 1 since otherwise my counterexample will apply. But this seems also wrong: I was under the impression that in the special case $M = A$ the content function is the identity and hence $\varphi(1) = 1$??